# Async Function throwing errors and I cant see them

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

I'm new to Async functions and even node.js. I'm trying to crawl a website and grab some data from it. When crawling the website my code randomly throws an ugly error:

```
    (node:6128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:75
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (c:\projects\ultipro-crawler\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:122:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (c:\projects\ultipro-crawler\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
    at DOMWorld.evaluate (c:\projects\ultipro-crawler\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\DOMWorld.js:112:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (c:\projects\ultipro-crawler\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.evaluate (c:\projects\ultipro-crawler\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:827:43)
    at Page.<anonymous> (c:\projects\ultipro-crawler\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
    at c:\projects\ultipro-crawler\phantom.js:21:30
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:6128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6128) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

at the bottom of the error i can see that its telling me i have an unhanded promise rejection but im not sure how to correct my code to account for this. Im new to using promises and Async functions and cant seem to find the error in general here.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const oportunities = [];
    const opportunity = {
        title: '',
        desc: '',
        category: '',
        reqName: '',
        hours: '',
        postingDate: '',
        address: ''
    };

    await page.goto('https://recruiting2.ultipro.com/PUB1004PSCU/JobBoard/d433f5c3-37c8-4bcf-a3af-248a707c7d31/?q=&o=postedDateDesc');

    const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('.opportunity .row .col-lg-20 h3 a').innerText
    });
    const desc = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('.opportunity .hidden-xs.paragraph').innerText
    });

    opportunity.title = title;
    opportunity.desc = desc;


    console.log(opportunity); 

    browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: since you're using async await, you can wrap it in a try/catch , `try { await promise()} catch(e) {console.log(e)}`, and then inspect the error if you're curious about it.

Comment: i couldn't find an image of a cod throwing an ugly error, but please enjoy this [image of a woman throwing an ugly cod](https://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/07/21/12/2AB390DF00000578-0-image-a-43_1437477026958.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't capture errors from the outer scope of an async IIFE. Either you try/catch all the code inside your IIFE:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const oportunities = [];
    const opportunity = {
      title: '',
      desc: '',
      category: '',
      reqName: '',
      hours: '',
      postingDate: '',
      address: ''
    };

    await page.goto('https://recruiting2.ultipro.com/PUB1004PSCU/JobBoard/d433f5c3-37c8-4bcf-a3af-248a707c7d31/?q=&o=postedDateDesc');

    const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelector('.opportunity .row .col-lg-20 h3 a').innerText
    });
    const desc = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelector('.opportunity .hidden-xs.paragraph').innerText
    });

    opportunity.title = title;
    opportunity.desc = desc;


    console.log(opportunity);

    browser.close();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
})();
```

use promises at top level scope:

```
async function doJob() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const oportunities = [];
  const opportunity = {
    title: '',
    desc: '',
    category: '',
    reqName: '',
    hours: '',
    postingDate: '',
    address: ''
  };

  await page.goto('https://recruiting2.ultipro.com/PUB1004PSCU/JobBoard/d433f5c3-37c8-4bcf-a3af-248a707c7d31/?q=&o=postedDateDesc');

  const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector('.opportunity .row .col-lg-20 h3 a').innerText
  });
  const desc = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector('.opportunity .hidden-xs.paragraph').innerText
  });

  opportunity.title = title;
  opportunity.desc = desc;


  console.log(opportunity);

  browser.close();
}

doJob()
  .catch(console.error)
```

or call your function from another function:

```
async function doJob () {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const oportunities = [];
  const opportunity = {
    title: '',
    desc: '',
    category: '',
    reqName: '',
    hours: '',
    postingDate: '',
    address: ''
  };

  await page.goto('https://recruiting2.ultipro.com/PUB1004PSCU/JobBoard/d433f5c3-37c8-4bcf-a3af-248a707c7d31/?q=&o=postedDateDesc');

  const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector('.opportunity .row .col-lg-20 h3 a').innerText
  });
  const desc = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector('.opportunity .hidden-xs.paragraph').innerText
  });

  opportunity.title = title;
  opportunity.desc = desc;


  console.log(opportunity);

  browser.close();
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await doJob()
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
```

Those are some options I can think of atm :)

Answer (score 1):

The website you are trying to scrape is loading content dynamically, so you should wait until the page is fully loaded (until all requests are done).
With Puppeteer you can use `waitUntil: 'networkidle0` :

> consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 0
>   network connections for at least 500 ms.

here a simple example using `waitUntil` and with simple error handling :

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const oportunities = [];
    const opportunity = {
        title: '',
        desc: '',
        category: '',
        reqName: '',
        hours: '',
        postingDate: '',
        address: ''
    };

    let url = 'https://recruiting2.ultipro.com/PUB1004PSCU/JobBoard/d433f5c3-37c8-4bcf-a3af-248a707c7d31/?q=&o=postedDateDesc';
    await page.goto(url, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
        try {
            return document.querySelector('.opportunity .row .col-lg-20 h3 a').innerText
        }
          catch(err) {
            return err

          }
    });
    const desc = await page.evaluate(() => {
        try {
            return document.querySelector('.opportunity .hidden-xs.paragraph').innerText
        }
          catch(err) {
            return err

          }
    });

    opportunity.title = title;
    opportunity.desc = desc;


    console.log(opportunity); 

    browser.close();
})();
```

The output is :

```
{ title: 'Canvas Consultant',
  desc: '• LEARN about our members, hear them, and understand their situations. • EDUCATE our members on the ways we can help them afford life. • PROVIDE meaningful, careful, focused and ethical lending solutions. • 
PROCESS transactions like deposits, withdrawals, transfers, and payments with consummate professionalism. • PERFORM advanced frontline transactions like IRAs, CDs, wire transfers, and calmly handle disputes. • GROW with us by immersing in financial industry trends, products, services and technological advances. • SHARE your knowledge on effective practices, competitive intelligence, and business opportunities. • STAND shoulder-to-shoulder with our members and your Canvas teammates through our peaks and valleys.',
  category: '',
  reqName: '',
  hours: '',
  postingDate: '',
  address: '' }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is visible on your first line:
`Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null`

either `document.querySelector('.opportunity .row .col-lg-20 h3 a')` returns null
or `document.querySelector('.opportunity .hidden-xs.paragraph')` returns null

Comment: Yes this is because of the way in which puppeteer is waiting for the page to load before grabbing the data, sometimes it work sometimes it doesnt. What im trying to figure out here is how to use a catch with an async function

Comment: Ohhhh, I misunderstood. I though you couldn't find it in your stacktrace. You can just wrap it in a try/catch block